# Using third-party Web Components with Lightning Web Components

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is it possible to use third-party standard Web Components with Lightning Web Components?
I have seen the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_third_party_library) about third-party libraries. But what about web components? Has anyone tried to integrate those into your own Lightning Web Components?

Comment: Do you mean using react in LWC?

Comment: Not React, Web Components. E.g. there's a growing repository of these: https://www.webcomponents.org/ and many more published through npm. And I can't wrap my head around integrating them with LWC. First, they are usually published as ES6 modules, with a lot of dependencies, so I can't import them from Static Resources (or can I?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible to use standard web components in LWC nor in Aura. The [`customElement.defines`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define) API to define a native custom element is currently blocked by Locker because of the security implications this API has.

Comment: That's a pity. But thank you for confirming this. But I imagine we can still build a web component application and place it inside an Aura `lightning:container`?

Comment: Locker doesn't run in `ligthning:container` so native web components should work as expected.